# Wifi not working on my Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, dell, broadcom

Wifi stopped working on my Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell XPS 13 Ultrabook. I looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) question and ran the wireless script. [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/21912408/) is the link to the script I generated. Can someone please help me with the situation.

I don't see any Wifi networks. I tried reinstalling the Broadcom drivers and it didn't work.When I search for additional drivers in my system settings, it already shows that BCM4352 driver is in use.

Comment: What is the resullt of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe wl`? I suspect Secure Boot.

Comment: Did you try rebooting your computer?

Comment: Yes, I did try rebooting. No success.

Comment: @chili555 This is what I go when I pasted this command. I am new to Ubuntu, so I might have done this wrong. I just hit the command 'sudo modprobe wl' and I got 

modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available

Comment: Yea, I switched off the secure boot and wifi connections started showing up without reinstalling bcmwl-kernel-source

Comment: but is it safe to boot with Secure Boot off? What threats can we expect?